# Curtiosity and dretful

Tags: meaning

In [The Elephant's Child](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/2781/2781-h/2781-h.htm#link2H_4_0005) by Rudyard Kipling he writes

> But there was one Elephant--a new Elephant--an Elephant's Child--who
>   was full of 'satiable curtiosity, and that means he asked ever so many
>   questions.

and then later

> 'Have I seen a Crocodile?' said the Bi-Coloured-Python-Rock-Snake, in
>   a voice of dretful scorn. 'What will you ask me next?'

Are these simply made up words never to be seen again or is there some way of interpreting them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're not made up words, but rather made up spellings of the words "curiosity" and "dreadful".

I'm sure the non-standard spellings are deliberate. They're used by Kipling to give a distinctive voice to the narrator, who presumably has an imperfect knowledge of English.

Comment: For " 'satiable curtiosity" read "insatiable curiosity".

Comment: Do you have a feeling for what the voice should be? For example, if one read it out loud, what accent would be approprite?

Comment: I would guess that the narrator is supposed to be a native of India or Africa, where the British had colonies (Kipling himself was born in British-ruled India, so he may have borrowed some of the narrator's mispronunciations from the speech of real people he knew). The inner story of "The Elephant's Child" is set in Africa, but it's not clear to me if the "frame" with the narrator and "Best Beloved" is supposed to be located there too.

Answer (score 2):

A child's voice - these kind of phonological confusions young children often make. He is very young and rather naif elephant.

My son called "croissants" , "quizles" .

Also:  "I don't like kidleys Dad"  ..."Kidneys son" ......"I said kidleys, Dad!"